# How to export blender material files to Unity

Tags: materials, export, unity

[image]I made this car with blender and I used some materials in my design.
I exported car and materials. When I use in unity I can't see the materials.  I try a lot of way but I didn't fix this problem. ( I used the paint mode but I want this different materials like emission for highlights. )

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to export blender material files to Unity](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28360/how-to-export-blender-material-files-to-unity)

Comment: @RayMairlot the other question should be be closed as the duplicate of this question. This is the better question, plus the other one was migrated here.

Comment: To close this question even if it's two years old and help people who hit on this post:
Here is an answer from another contribution, that explains why it is **not** possible to export Blender materials to other rendering engines like unity.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)